# Why is Entity Framework 6.1 inconsistently retrieving related entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following (subset) in a SQL Server database that has been generated by Entity Framework 6.1 code-first:

[image: Database schema]

I then run the following query

```
var response = await Context.SurveyResponses 
            .Include(x => x.Answers) 
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Client.Id == clientId && 
            x.Survey.Id == surveyId && 
            !x.CompletedOn.HasValue);
```

In 99% of cases, the `Question` object on the `Answers` collection would be populated. However in rate 1% of cases, it would be null.

This problem was solved by improving the `Include` statement as follows

```
var response = await Context.SurveyResponses 
            .Include(x => x.Answers.Select(y => y.Question))
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Client.Id == clientId && 
            x.Survey.Id == surveyId && 
            !x.CompletedOn.HasValue);
```

However what I'd like to understand is why the first query ever worked? How did it know to include the `Question` property of the `Answers` object? Why did it work in some cases and not others?

Answer (score 2):

EF will auto-fixup what it can.  If your context had the data already, it would fill it in for you.

For example, assuming SurveryResponseAnswer with id of 1 has a question of id 1, then:

```
var db=new Context();
var test=db.Questions.Where(x=>x.id==1);
var result=db.SurveyResponseAnswers.Where(x=>x.id==1);
// result's Question property is filled in

var db=new Context();
var result=db.SurveyResponseAnswers.Where(x=>x.id==1);
// result's Question property is not filled in
```

Comment: @peterbridger this raises an interesting point, your context should be kept as short-living as possible (eg only one unit of work). the more items you get on the context the slower it will get.